# QT Qtcpsocket client lose connection but do not emit disconnect signal

Tags: qt, sockets

I used QTcpSocket to receive data from server , i have set the option to keep_alive.
At beginning the socket connects to the host , and can receive the server push data. After a while with server not pushing data,  client could not receive the data pushed by server without emit disconnect signal. And the socket state is in connection state.

But when i plug off the wire from the net port , the client socket could emit disconnect signal.

What happened to QTcpsocket ?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: "when i plug off the wire from the net port , the client socket could emit disconnect signal" Not necessarily. This is platform- and settings-dependent. Sometimes the platform imposes a timeout in spite of the physical connection being lost.